# Android App crashes with Simple draw to canvas, disp Bitmap

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    int height = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
    int width = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(height, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.button){

        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the above code snippet for Android Studio would cause the app to crash constantly? I'm new to Android Studio and I want to get used to building rectangles and shapes before anything more, but it seems I'm having difficulty with even that.

Displays error of drawing Bitmap with values not > 0, but the issue is that after using a print function in onClick, grabbing height or width from either window or the imageView, I am returned a value > 0, so I don't understand.

Comment: Please show the error you get (e.g. logcat ...)

Comment: @JonGoodwin , Displays error of drawing Bitmap with values not > 0, but the issue is that after using a print function in onClick, grabbing height or width from either window or the imageView, I am returned a value > 0, so I dont understand

Comment: people are trying to close down the question (with good reason).... **"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"** Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to ask a question. Also show what you have tried to do to fix the problem. You get a badge for it ;O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting height and width in onCreate method before view has been drawn and thus resulting in returning height 0, width 0 since android system don't know exact width and height of view.You can use some method like post(Runnable) to know if view has drawn.Modify you code like below.

```
View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
view.post( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         width  = view.getMeasuredWidth();
         height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
         bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(height, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
         canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    }
});
```